# Rails Form Select Requirement with partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a form with a `.select` field that loads a list of states via partial. The requirement isn't being enforced on state and I'm not sure why. It lets you submit the form with the default blank value 'State'

Would appreciate any help figuring out where my syntax is wrong on this form? If this looks foreign, using SLIM instead of HTML.

```
= f.select :state, nil, include_blank: 'State', required: true # not working
  = render partial: 'addresses/states'
= f.text_field :zip, placeholder: 'Zip',  required: true, pattern:'[0-9]*' # works
```

The states partial looks like this:

```
option value="AL" AL
option value="AK" AK
option value="AZ" AZ
option value="AR" AR
...
```

Comment: Try this `f.select :state, '', { :include_blank => 'State' }, :required => true`

Comment: @pavan -- Thank you, that works with including the blank `state`, but it's not enforcing the requirement of selecting one of the state values. Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't seen anything like that. I mean providing values for the select using a partial.

Comment: It works, helps abstract it out. The other option is to put all the states in an array and use that variable instead of the partial, but ideally I'd like to keep the partial..

Comment: Do you have associated model validations?

Comment: We do have server-side validations, but i'd rather this is caught before the POST request.